# Correct Python typing in subclasses

Tags: python, oop, python-typing

I have the following code:

```
# base message
class BaseMessage:
    # may accept any headers
    def __init__(self, headers) -> None:
        self.headers = headers


class PongMessageHeaders:
    def __init__(self, pong_header: str) -> None:
        self.pong_header = pong_header


# pong message
class PongMessage(BaseMessage):
    # uses pong-specific headers
    def __init__(self, headers: PongMessageHeaders) -> None:
        super().__init__(headers)


class PingMessageHeaders:
    def __init__(self, ping_header: str) -> None:
        self.ping_header = ping_header


# ping message
class PingMessage(BaseMessage):
    #  uses ping-specific headers
    def __init__(self, headers: PingMessageHeaders) -> None:
        super().__init__(headers)


ping = PingMessage(PingMessageHeaders("ping header"))
# I don't get type hint here
print(ping.headers.ping_header)

pong = PongMessage(PongMessageHeaders("pong header"))
# I don't get type hint here
print(pong.headers.pong_header)
```

I expect `ping.headers` to have the "PingMessageHeaders" type, so I could get a hint about the "ping_header" field from IDE. But it does not work.
The same is about `pong.headers`.

Currently, I figured out these ways to make it work:

- 1

  - Add abstract `BaseMessage.headers` property
  - Define it in the "PingMessage", the return type is "PingMessageHeaders"
- 2

  - After the `super().__init__(headers)` line write `self.headers = header`

But I am not sure I like it...

Is there any other way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but you can just add the type to `headers`:

```py
class PingMessageHeaders:
    def __init__(self, ping_header: str) -> None:
        self.ping_header = ping_header
    
class BaseMessage:
    def __init__(self, headers: PingMessageHeaders) -> None:
        self.raw_headers = headers

class PingMessage(BaseMessage):
    def __init__(self, headers: PingMessageHeaders) -> None:
        super().__init__(headers)


p = PingMessage(PingMessageHeaders("example_header"))
print(p.raw_headers.ping_header)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
But I don't want to tie the BaseMessage to the specific headers class.
I may have a lot of messages each of them having specific headers.

I extended my question.

Answer (score 0):

Although you specified `headers` to be `PingMessageHeaders` in `PingMessage` but it is only useful in that type checkers will tell you if you're passing the correct type to the super's `header` or not. BUT the `header` in the base class `BaseMessage` doesn't have any type hint so it is considered `Any`.

You need to fill that too:

```py
from __future__ import annotations


class BaseMessage:
    def __init__(self, headers: PingMessageHeaders) -> None:
        self.raw_headers = headers


class PingMessageHeaders:
    def __init__(self, ping_header: str) -> None:
        self.ping_header = ping_header


class PingMessage(BaseMessage):
    def __init__(self, headers: PingMessageHeaders) -> None:
        super().__init__(headers)


p = PingMessage(PingMessageHeaders("example_header"))
print(p.raw_headers.ping_header)
```

`raw_headers` only get initialized in super class `BaseMessage` from the parameter `headers`. Having that type hinted, type checker can say that `p.raw_headers.ping_header` is `str`.

The first line is to tell Python to lazy evaluate the annotations so that you don't get "not defined" error.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
But I don't want to tie the BaseMessage to the specific headers class.
I may have a lot of messages each of them having specific headers.

I extended my question